# Validate custom fields added above the “Add To Cart” in Single Product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, validation, woocommerce, custom-fields

I have added the form above the Add To Cart button in single product page in WooCommerce and I want to validate the form, like without filling the form user should not be able to click the `Add To Cart` Button.

My Code Added In `functions.php`:

```
function add_name_on_tshirt_field() {
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled"><table class="variations" cellspacing="0" width="100px">

        <tbody><tr>
          <td class="label" style="width:100px"><label for="color">Agent Name</label></td>
          <td class="value">
              <input type="text" name="name-on-tshirt" value="" required/>                      
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td class="label"><label for="color">Title</label></td>
          <td class="value">
              <input type="text" name="name-on-tshirt" value="" required/>                      
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td class="label"><label for="color">Phone No</label></td>
          <td class="value">
              <input type="text" name="name-on-tshirt" value="" required/>                      
          </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </br>
 ';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'add_name_on_tshirt_field' );
```

[image]

Using the above code, the form has been added but how to validate the form before clicking on the Add To Cart button.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your fields need to be inside add to cart form, so using `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` action hook instead of `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form`…

There is a mistake in your code as all fields have the same attribute "name" value.

Replace that with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_name_on_tshirt_field' );
function add_name_on_tshirt_field() {
    echo '<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled">
        <table class="variations" cellspacing="0" width="100px">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="label" style="width:100px"><label for="color">' . __("Agent Name", "woocommerce") . '</label></td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="text" name="tshirt_name" value="" required/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label"><label for="color">' . __("Title", "woocommerce") . '</label></td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="text" name="tshirt_title" value="" required/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label"><label for="color">' . __("Phone No", "woocommerce") . '</label></td>
                <td class="value">
                    <input type="text" name="tshirt_phone" value="" required/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </br>';
}
```

Then you will be able to use `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` hook for field validation

```
// Field validation
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'validate_name_on_tshirt_field' );
function validate_name_on_tshirt_field( $passed ) {
    $error_notice = array(); // Initializing
    
    if ( isset($_POST['tshirt_name']) && empty($_POST['tshirt_name']) ) {
        $passed = false;
        $error_notice[] = __('"Agent Name" is a required field', 'woocommerce');
    }
    
    if ( isset($_POST['tshirt_title']) && empty($_POST['tshirt_title']) ) {
        $passed = false;
        $error_notice[] = __('"Title" is a required field', 'woocommerce');
    }
    
    if ( isset($_POST['tshirt_phone']) && empty($_POST['tshirt_phone']) ) {
        $passed = false;
        $error_notice[] = __('"Phone No" is a required field', 'woocommerce');
    }
    
    // Display errors notices
    if ( ! empty($error_notice) ) {
        wc_add_notice( implode('<br>', $error_notice), 'error' );
    }
    
    return $passed;
}
```

Now you need to save fields data as custom cart item data and display them in cart and checkout pages:

```
// Save as custom cart item data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_custom_data', 10, 2 );
function add_cart_item_custom_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['tshirt_name']) && ! empty($_POST['tshirt_name']) ) {
        $cart_item_data['tshirt_name'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['tshirt_name']);
    }
    
    if ( isset($_POST['tshirt_title']) && ! empty($_POST['tshirt_title']) ) {
        $cart_item_data['tshirt_title'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['tshirt_title']);
    }
    
    if ( isset($_POST['tshirt_phone']) && ! empty($_POST['tshirt_phone']) ) {
        $cart_item_data['tshirt_phone'] = sanitize_text_field($_POST['tshirt_phone']);
    }
    
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Display in cart and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );
function display_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    if ( isset($cart_item['tshirt_name']) ) {
        $cart_data[] = array( "name" => __("Agent name", "woocommerce"),  "value" => $cart_item['tshirt_name'] );
    }

    if ( isset($cart_item['tshirt_title']) ) {
        $cart_data[] = array( "name" => __("Title", "woocommerce"),  "value" => $cart_item['tshirt_title'] );
    }

    if ( isset($cart_item['tshirt_phone']) ) {
        $cart_data[] = array( "name" => __("Phone No", "woocommerce"),  "value" => $cart_item['tshirt_phone'] );
    }
    
    return $cart_data;
}
```

To finish you need to save fields data as custom order item data and display them in orders and emails:

```
// Display on orders and email notifications (save as custom order item meta data)
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'display_on_orders_and_emails', 10, 4 );
function display_on_orders_and_emails( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( isset($values['tshirt_name']) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( __("Agent name", "woocommerce"), $values['tshirt_name'] );
    }

    if ( isset($values['tshirt_title']) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( __("Title", "woocommerce"), $values['tshirt_title'] );
    }

    if ( isset($values['tshirt_phone']) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( __("Phone No", "woocommerce"), $values['tshirt_phone'] );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.